# Voltage at Collector of NPN less than Minimum allowed for High

Tags: transistors, npn

I have connected the collector of a NPN BJT (DTC144EE) to the Power_ON pin of my lte module (HL7588).

The pin is internally pulled up by a 100k resistor to 1.8V. The module is powered on by driving the PWR_ON signal low (I send 1.8V from my controller to the base of U$1). 
[image]

However, I ran a simulation in TINA and am seeing .85V at the collector (when I want device in OFF state) when the minimum of a a high signal should be 1.33V.

[image]

On U4s Data sheet:

[image]

Any ideas on what is going on here? This is the transistor Sierra recommends for both Power_on and Reset signals so it is confusing.

Comment: First, what voltage are you putting on to the base of T1, and second, where is the current-limiting resistor at the base of T1?

Comment: I'll install TINA and look for setup issue. Can you link your model file?

Comment: Tim, there is no current limiting resistor at the base, its purely high/low signal with no power consideration therefore I thought it wasn't necessary. Voltage at the base is 1.8 from my controller

Comment: @wgthompson the DCT144E has a built-in 47K resistor in series with the base.  Also another 47K resistor built in, across base-emitter.   If this isn't in your transistor library, then you need to include these two resistors, else simulation tells lies.   DCT144E is npn bjt transistor with built-in bias resistors, NOT just a standard bjt transistor.   (A standard npn transistor needs a 1K resistor or higher, in series with base lead.   Otherwise it's like an LED put directly across a power supply: a bright flash, then it stops working.

Comment: @wbeaty thanks your right I should have specified those internal resistances, but they are in fact included in the model macro for the transistor

Comment: The datasheet says, hfe current-gain is 68, and for Vinp=1.8V, collector current is around 5mA.  The Vout with a 100K pullup may actually be below 0.1VDC (see datasheet fig. 5 graph,off the left side.)   ALSO, try an external pull-up resistor like 2.2K.   According to fig. 5, that should actually make the Vout become lower.  (But it might not be needed, in a real world circuit.)

Answer (score 0):

NPN datasheet says

[image]

So worst case drop IR= 500n  delta V= 0.5uA*0.1M = 0.05V drop from 1.8V  so ??? mystery leakage.

We cannot look any deeper without your SCH file.

Very primitive buggy Editor. It reads 0V out ?? with erroneous Exponent.

[image]

**Definitely a fault in  LIB Model file...**
I edited SCM macro file to change C:\user\willi... to  H:\Downloads\DTC144EET1.LIB

### Incorrect transfer function

[image]

Comment: Whats the easiest way to share the sch file on here

Comment: ok try this link

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1FD5NMKi715rtbXm2VA4P-7O3hzgNuXV_/view?usp=sharing

Comment: also need NPN TIna model file which has an error C:\Users\willi\Downloads\dtc144ee.lib

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1vUQJ4lOmlLmRFb9bNf-iP4xT6CfxWoX0/view?usp=sharing

Comment: should be the transistor macro

Comment: hmm C:\Users\willi\Downloads\dtc144ee.lib shown in TSM file

Comment: sorry Tina free editor for Outputs is too cryptic for editing with DRC and no Ref Designations . Can not find SCM part in library since no .lib file

Comment: wont work without ,,,ee.lib file

Comment: need .TSC schematic file too

Comment: haha I know, I hate the tinas editor as well. Trying to resolve the lib issue so I can give you the link

Comment: I found a couple sources but ROHM has 0 bytes for the LIB file and 2 other formats which tells me something's wrong with LIB file so I use 10k PUllup and Vout is now 1.25V  argh

Comment: try this .cir file for the transistor

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1gSy-Q3fxtQg88Ibqde-nO4bwU7my80_s/view?usp=sharing

Comment: by the way, that graph shows the voltage I was seeing ...  around .85 @ 0 input V

Comment: Without correct simulation library, instead try just using a common npn, like 2N2222 or a 2N4401, then add those two 47K resistors shown in the online PDF datasheet for the DCT144E.  (Normally, npn transistors have no built-in resistors.  The DCT is actually a simple O.C. logic inverter.)

Comment: The datasheet says, hfe current-gain is 68, and for Vinp=1.8V, collector current max is around 5mA.    ALSO, try an external pull-up resistor like 2.2K.   According to fig. 5 in the online spec sheet, that should actually make the Vout become lower.  (But it might not be needed, in the real world device.  You'd have to actually try it.)

Comment: This LIB and TINA are not ready for me to debug . with buried paths , no user paths, TinA.exe errors due to missing paths with User\public or downloads.  Transfer function works though , even if it is wrong

Answer (score 0):

The transistor already has two 47k resistors as a voltage divider on its base. You should have shown them in your schematic to us.
Your leakage current is 9.4uA which is much higher than it is spec'd. Replace the transistor without frying it with your soldering blow torch.

Oh, is your voltmeter input resistance loading down the voltage measurement?

Comment: what was the calculation for the leakage current?